# Using the Implicit Function Theorem, prove that it can be solved.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Show that the equation $x + y - z + \cos(xyz) = 0$ can be solved for $z = f(x,y)$ in the neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: Do you know what the implicit function theorem says?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that

$$ \theta \sim 0 \implies \cos(\theta) \sim 1.  $$

**Added:**

$$ x + y - z + \cos(xyz) \sim x + y - z + 1 = 0 \implies z = 1+x+y. $$